# How to use pdfminer.six

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, text-extraction

I am trying to extract text from pdf using `pdfminer` in python 3.x. I have installed it using the following command

```
pip3 install pdfminer.six
```

when I try to extract text using below command, I am getting an error

```
pdf2txt.py sample.pdf
```

> Error: pdf2txt.py: command not found

I have read the official documentation they have shown the same steps that  I have followed above but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six) assumes that `.py` scripts can automatically run. But that is not the case for all operating systems (if it is possible, your local system doesn't need to be set up to make it work).

To start `PDFminer` manually from the command line, use the regular way of starting a Python script:

```
python pdf2txt.py sample.pdf
```

and it will run the script and exit back to the command line when done. If you get an error somewhere or want to stay in Python for some reason, you can use

```
python -i pdf2txt.py sample.pdf
```

Comment: I am getting this error `python: can't open file 'pdf2txt.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: @OliviaBrown: how comfortable are you in working on the command line? You must be in the folder containing pdf2txt, and Python must be in your path. According to the github page, pdf2txt.py can be found in the tools folder.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue...where is this pdf2txt.py file located?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty late but still if it helps you, do the following in terminal:

1. Type `ls` in the terminal and it will return a list of files. Check if `pdf2text.py` is present in that list and `sample.pdf` should also be there.
2. If these 2 files are not shown in the list, it means you are in a different directory, so you'll have to navigate to the proper directory where both of these files are present or you'll have to give the name of the file along with its path.
3. Once you are in the correct directory, just give the command:

   ```
   python pdf2text.py sample.pdf
   ```

   It should work provided the argument parser does not require an identifier.

   Alternatively, provide the full path to each:

   ```
    python /home/you/downloads/something/pdf2text.py /home/you/downloads/something/sample.pdf
   ```

   ... where of course replace `/home/you/downloads/something` with the actual path where you have these files.